# Spider with brown zig zags on abdomen and black head

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Found this spider roaming around my room the other day.. can someone tell me the species?

Location: Central KY, USA

[image]

[image]

Also, [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPhAOKltTKg) a video of him moving around in a glass candle lid, where you can get a really good look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you've found a male steatoda triangulosa or triangulate cobweb (weaver) spider
[image]

More info:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulate_cobweb_spider
http://lancaster.unl.edu/pest/resources/triangulatespider.shtml